# How do I get my server to print the input from my client class?

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I'm creating a client server program and it works however I want my server to be able to output the input from my client classes but i've little idea how to do this exactly? Obviously it'd be linked to my input/output stream but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please tell us what you tried and provide the code you are having trouble with

Comment: Sorry, edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be better using the `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` to communicate between Server and Client.

Implement `Runnable` into your Server class and add the `run()` method into it. In the `while (true)` loop, receive data from the Client and output them like this:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            String line = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println(line);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In your Client class, do something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String line = sc.nextLine();
dos.writeUTF(line);
```

Hope this helps.